# Accessing information from extended modelform

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I cannot access information from a modelform I extended. Since the model was saved as mentor I assume accessing information from it would be through something along the line of

```
user.mentor.*informationname*
```

This is what i have in my views.py

```
class TeacherSignUpView(CreateView):
    model = User
    form_class = TeacherSignUpForm
    template_name = 'registration/signup_form.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs['user_type'] = 'teacher'
        return super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        user = form.save()
        # user.set_password(form.cl)
        login(self.request, user)
        return redirect('teachers:app-instructor-dashboard')
...
def payment_view(request):
    form = MentorPaymentForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MentorPaymentForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=request.user)
        if form.is_valid():
            user,mentor = form.save(commit=False)
            return redirect('teachers:payment_view')
    else:
        form = MentorPaymentForm(instance=request.user)
    return render(request, 'classroom/teachers/app-instructor-billing.html', {'form': form})
```

models.py:

```
class Mentor(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='mentor')
    linkedin = models.URLField(max_length=200,null=True,blank=True)
    photo = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to='media', default='default.jpg')
    address = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
    invoice_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False, blank=False)
    account_num = models.IntegerField(default=1234)
    bank_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False)
    branch_code = models.IntegerField(default=1234)

    def __str__(self):
        return "Profile of user {}".format(self.user.username)
```

and forms.py

```
class TeacherSignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=100)
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    linkedin = forms.URLField(max_length=200)
    address = forms.CharField(max_length=500)
    invoice_name = forms.CharField(max_length=200)
    account_num = forms.IntegerField()
    bank_name = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
    branch_code = forms.IntegerField()

    class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
        model = User
        fields = ('email', 'username', 'first_name', 'last_name')

    def save(self, commit=True):
        self.instance.is_teacher = True
        user = super(UserCreationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
        user.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']
        user.save()
        mentor = Mentor.objects.get_or_create(
            user=user,
            linkedin=self.cleaned_data['linkedin'],
            address=self.cleaned_data['address'],
            invoice_name=self.cleaned_data['invoice_name'],
            account_num=self.cleaned_data['account_num'],
            bank_name=self.cleaned_data['bank_name'],
            branch_code=self.cleaned_data['branch_code'],
        )
        return user
```

When I try access invoice_name using

```
user.mentor.invoice_name
```

I do not get anything coming up in the template

Answer (score 0):

Your `Mentor` is linked to your `User` by a foreign key, so one user can have many mentors. As you can see,  your `User` model does not have a mentor attribute. To get all `Mentor` instances linked to a specific user do

```
user.mentor_set.all()
```

This returns a queryset. To access information from the first related Mentor instance you can do

```
user.mentor_set.first().invoice_name
```

or slice the returned queryset.

Having said this,  I am not sure whether you actually want the possibility that a user has many mentors. If not a `OneToOne` field might be better. With a `OneToOne` field your syntax would be correct:

```
user.mentor.invoice_name
```